# Twitter cards not working on my site

Tags: angularjs, twitter, twitter-card

I'm trying to share some content of my AngularJS website in twitter using next link:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.yanpy.com%2Fes%2Fblog%2Frutas-para-navegar-por-ibiza-y-formentera">
```

When I click on it, the Twitter share page is opened. However, I would like to use Twitter Cards. I added this twitter cards tags in my page:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Yanpy_com">     
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Sailing routes around Ibiza and Formentera">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Post description">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://yanpy.test.s3.amazonaws.com/img/blog/sailing-routes-around-ibiza-formentera/cala-salada-ibiza-1.jpg">
```

But for some reason it is not working. I used the Twitter card validator with my url: `http://www.test.yanpy.com/es/blog/rutas-para-navegar-por-ibiza-y-formentera`

It looks like it's ok. However, when called from my anchor in my website I just see the text field.

Comment: As far as I know, the twitter share page *does not* show a card preview.

Comment: Do you mean it will only show the card when shared?

Comment: Ouuhhhh shi..... you are right! It was working. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

@AnidMonsur is right don't show a card preview into the twitter web page, but you can see the preview into the validator, https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: validator show WARN:  No metatags found even it have all the meta tags? do you know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://..." />
```

instead of:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://...">
```